# JS retrieve filtered data in google sheet script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a HTML form which gets data from google sheet.
To get ALL records in the sheet I use the following code .

I am now trying to add code to filter data-

(1) to get Only ONE Row where Col A meets some criteria
Ex. Get data from Row where Column A = "123"...Column A has the Unique ID's

(2)to get only those those rows where Column F is blank

Please help...

```
 function read_value(request,ss){

 var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput(),
 data    = {};

  var sheet="sheet1";

data.records = readData_(ss, sheet);

 var callback = request.parameters.callback;

 if (callback === undefined) {
 output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
 } else {
 output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
      }
 output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

  return output;
      }


 function readData_(ss, sheetname, properties) {

 if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
 properties = getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname);
 properties = properties.map(function(p) { return p.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); });
 }

var rows = getDataRows_(ss, sheetname),
data = [];

for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
var row     = rows[r],
record  = {};

for (var p in properties) {
record[properties[p]] = row[p];
}

data.push(record);

 }
return data;
 }

function getDataRows_(ss, sheetname) {
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

return sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() -1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();

 }



function getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname) {
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

return sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to respond to your question other than give you an example that gets all the data from a given sheet in a spreadsheet and returns it to an html page and displays it.

Here's a simple way to get all of the data on a sheet.  It's currently just a dialog contained in a Spreadsheet but one could easily turn it into a webapp.

Google Apps Script:

```
function getMyData(dObj) {//function called from html in with window.onload
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(dObj.sheetname);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hl='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==dObj.colACriteria){//you can put your filtering criteria here
      hl+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
        hl+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
      }
      hl+='</tr>';
    }
  }
  hl+='</table>';
  return hl;
}

function showGetMyDataDialog() {//this launches the html as a modeless dialog
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('getdata').setTitle('My Data');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Get My Data');
}
```

and here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
   window.onload=function(){
    var dObj={sheetname:'Index',colACriteria:'123'};
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){//this is the call back function that put the data into a div
      document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML=hl;
    })
    .getMyData(dObj);
  };

  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="mydata"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi-Thanks for that- I already get All data in my code - what i need is to filter the data based on criteria as in (1) and (2) in the original post-

Comment: I added the code to the `getMyData()` function where I would do the filtering.  You can probably pass an object like `var dObj={sheetname:'Index', colACritera:'some value'};` There are [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) in the parameters you can pass in client to server communications